# How to access all Lineitems attributes from Google DFP using php client library

Tags: php, google-dfp

I'm using DFP API client library **v201711**. I run the example code for listing all LineItems from DFP (examples/Dfp/v201711/LineItemService/GetAllLineItems.php). But in given example, it shows only ID, Name of LineItems by using below functions.

For example:

```
foreach ($page->getResults() as $lineItem) {
      printf(
          "%d) Line item with ID %d and name '%s' was found.\n",
          $i++,
          $lineItem->getId(),
          $lineItem->getName()
      );
}
```

How can I get other attributes of lineItems such as order name, start and end dates, campaign dimensions and advertiser details etc?

Please help me. I was stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it only returns **id** and **name** because these are the only attributes explicitly requested in your code sample. 
Use other getter methods (get**PropertyName**, where **PropertyName** is the attribute you need) to extract the attributes you need.

A comprehensive list of the available attributes can be found in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201711/LineItemService)